# What finite subgroup of $SU(N)$ most closely approximates $SU(N)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups

What finite subgroup $G$ of $SU(N)$ most closely approximates $SU(N)$?

I'm hoping that the answer isn't too dependent on the precise definition of "approximates," but I'll offer a definition anyway to make the question well-posed: consider the fundamental representation of $SU(N)$ by $N\times N$ unitary matrices, and define the distance between two matrices $A,B$ by
$$
 |A-B|=\frac{1}{N}\text{trace}\big((A-B)^\dagger (A-B)\big).
\tag{1}
$$
The error in the approximation can be quantified by
$$
 \max_{u\in SU(N)} \min_{g\in G} |u-g|.
\tag{2}
$$
The normalization of (1) is meant to give a more fair comparison between different values of $N$.

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense. As you increase the size of the subgroup $G$, you should expect it to make the quantity defined in (2) smaller and smaller. So, it's likely that no finite group will minimize your error term. 

As a stupid example: take $S^1$ and approximate successively with $n^{th}$ roots of unity. Your error tends to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: I mean more that you should be skeptical of defining an error quantity that fails to return a good result for the simple case. It may not be possible to find such a sequence of approximations, but maybe this should be cause for concern.

Comment: While it is true in general that an optimum of this "error" may not exist, in the case of $SU(n)$ there is good reason to believe it does; for instance, I suspect the binary icosahedral group is the optimal subgroup of $SU(2)$, since all subgroups of higher order are cyclic/dihedral. Answering the question for other values of $n$ would probably require a classification of discrete subgroups of $SU(n)$, which has at least been done for $n\le 4$. [This mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17072/the-finite-subgroups-of-sun) discusses some references.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis  Okay, I see where you were coming from now. Thanks for clarifying. I deleted my earlier comments that missed your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a positive lower bound on the approximation of $SU(N)$ by its finite subgroup (for $N\ge 2$) due to Jordan's Lemma on finite subgroups of $SU(N)$: Every finite subgroup contains an abelian subgroup of index $\le q(N)$.  See

*Turing, A. M.*, [**Finite approximations to Lie groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1968716), Ann. Math. (2) 39, 105-111 (1938). [ZBL0018.29801](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0018.29801).

As for an optimal finite subgroup, good luck with that, this sounds like one of the sphere packing problems which are notoriously difficult. Even optimal values of $q(N)$ in Jordan's theorem are still unknown although much work was done in this direction.

Comment: Note that $q(N)$ is known explicitly. It is $(N+1)!$ for sufficiently large $N$, where sufficiently large is somewhere in the 70s, if I remember correctly. (The bound is achieved by the symmetric group.)

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for the answer! I wasn't aware of Jordan's theorem/lemma. To make sure I understand its significance: if we consider such a "large" abelian subgroup $H$ of the finite group $G\subset SU(N)$, the fact that $H$ is abelian prevents it from "exploring" much of the $SU(N)$ manifold -- maybe restricted to some set of "orthogonal planes," or something like that. (That's my gut talking, not any clear mathematical insight.) And since the index of $H$ in $G$ is limited, this limits "how much" of $SU(N)$ can be explored by all of $G$. Is that vaguely the right idea?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Thank you for the comment! After seeing this answer and your comment, I found a 2007 paper "On Jordan's theorem for complex linear groups" (behind a paywall) whose abstract confirms what you said about $q(N)$, with $q(N)=(N+1)!$ for $N\geq 71$, achieved by the symmetric group. This is for $GL(N)$ instead of $SU(N)$, but I guess it still puts an upper bound on $q(N)$ for $SU(N)$, which goes a long way toward answering the intent of my question.

Comment: Note that every linear representation is conjugate to a unitary one.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly: Suppose that $[A,B]=1$. Then $||[A+tC, B+tC]-1||\le t\cdot Const$. Thus, if you take two matrices $A',  B'$ whose commutator is sufficiently far from $1$, they cannot be close to commuting matrices.